# Swift 4 Json Parse

Tags: json, swift

I need to throw this json data into the "arrayCategory" array above. How can I do it ?

> "Elektronik" and "Hobi" titles are not fixed. It is variable.
>
> Json Data

```
{
  "Elektronik": [
    {
      "kategoriisim": "AkÄ±llÄ± Saatler",
      "uyevarmi": "1"
    },
    {
      "kategoriisim": "Anakart",
      "uyevarmi": "1"
    } ],

  "Hobi": [
    {
      "kategoriisim": "Drone Multikopter",
      "uyevarmi": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

> > - Struct and Array .  I need to fill in the "dimensionalArray" array
>
> ExpandableNames "baslik" = The future of "Elektronik" data in json data
>
> ExpandableNames "kategori" = The sub-elements of the "Elektronik" circuit will come

```
    struct ExpandableNames {

        let baslik : String
        let kategori: [cellKategorilerData]
    }
    struct cellKategorilerData {
        var kategoriisim : String?
        var uyevarmi : String?
    }

    var dimensionalArray = [ExpandableNames]()
    var arrayKategoriData = [cellKategorilerData]()
```

> -

```
static func jsonSonucGetir(servlet:String,parametre:String) {

        let connectString = Connect.ConnectInfo

        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string:connectString.conString + "/" + servlet)!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        var postString = parametre
        postString = postString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)!
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

            if error != nil
            {
                print("error" , error)

            }

            if let urlContent = data
            {
                do
                {
                    let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject



                       ???

                }
                catch
                {
                    print("server hatasi")

                }
            }
        }

        task.resume()
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the keys are dynamic I recommend to decode the object as dictionary (`[String:[CellKategorilerData]]`)

```
let jsonString = """
{
    "Elektronik": [
        {"kategoriisim": "AkÄ±llÄ± Saatler", "uyevarmi": "1"},
        {"kategoriisim": "Anakart", "uyevarmi": "1"}
    ],
    "Hobi": [
        {"kategoriisim": "Drone Multikopter", "uyevarmi": "1"}
    ]
}
"""
```

---

```
struct CellKategorilerData : Decodable {
    let kategoriisim : String
    let uyevarmi : String
}
```

---

```
do {
    let data = Data(jsonString.utf8) 
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([String:[CellKategorilerData]].self, from: data)
    for (key, value) in result {
        print("key", key, "value", value)
    }
} catch { print(error) }
```